# Drupal 8 Include JS Libararies

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-8

I've attempted to include javascript via the asset inclusion engine in drupal 8 but I keep running into issues with JS files.

It seems like it is wanting to include the javascript file from a theme, and not the module.

module.libraries.yml

```
preview:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/preview.js: {preprocess: false}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupalSettings
ckeditor:
  remote: https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.0/standard/ckeditor.js
  version: 4.7.0
  js:
    https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.0/standard/ckeditor.js: { type: external }
```

module.module

```
function module_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id)
{
  // it is the plan edit form, lets hide some fields
  if($form_id=='node_plans_edit_form') {
    foreach([
      'field_currency',
      'field_plan_price',
      'field_length',
      'field_plan_trial_length',
      'field_plan_trial_length_interval',
      'field_purchase_endpoint',
      'field_su'
      ] as $disabledField) {
      $form[$disabledField]['#disabled'] = true;
    }
  }

  $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'module/ckeditor';
  $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'module/preview';


  $url = \Drupal::service('module.properties')->interface['url'];
  $form['#attached']['drupalSettings']['module']['ckeditor']['proto'] = explode(':', $url)[0];
  $form['#attached']['drupalSettings']['module']['ckeditor']['host'] = explode('//', $url)[1];

  return $form;
}
```

I get a stack trace when refreshing the cache and reloading the node-edit page:

```
User warning: The following theme is missing from the file system: smartott in drupal_get_filename() (line 236 of core/includes/bootstrap.inc).
drupal_get_filename('theme', 'module') (Line: 259)
drupal_get_path('theme', 'module') (Line: 390)
Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDiscoveryParser->drupalGetPath('theme', 'module') (Line: 85)
Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDiscoveryParser->buildByExtension('module') (Line: 87)
Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDiscoveryCollector->getLibraryDefinitions('module') (Line: 66)
Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDiscoveryCollector->resolveCacheMiss('module') (Line: 148)
Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheCollector->get('module') (Line: 44)
Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDiscovery->getLibrariesByExtension('module') (Line: 58)
Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDiscovery->getLibraryByName('module', 'ckeditor') (Line: 54)
Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDependencyResolver->doGetDependencies(Array) (Line: 31)
Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDependencyResolver->getLibrariesWithDependencies(Array) (Line: 104)
Drupal\Core\Asset\AssetResolver->getLibrariesToLoad(Object) (Line: 116)
Drupal\Core\Asset\AssetResolver->getCssAssets(Object, 1) (Line: 291)
Drupal\Core\Render\HtmlResponseAttachmentsProcessor->processAssetLibraries(Object, Array) (Line: 161)
Drupal\Core\Render\HtmlResponseAttachmentsProcessor->processAttachments(Object) (Line: 45)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\HtmlResponseSubscriber->onRespond(Object, 'kernel.response', Object) (Line: 111)
Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.response', Object) (Line: 184)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->filterResponse(Object, Object, 1) (Line: 166)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 64)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 99)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 78)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 50)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 652)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

If included successfully my JS file will dump some info to the browser console, but that has not happened yet. It feels like this is a bug or I'm missing some parameter, as I'm following the documentation completely.

Answer (score 2):

Your `module_form_alter()` requires theme's javascript files:

```
$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'smartott/ckeditor';
$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'smartott/preview';
```

If you want to load your module's javascript, considering your module's name is, well, `module`, require the library like this:

```
$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'module/preview';
```

Where `module` is module name, and `preview` is the name of the library as defined in `module.library.yml` file.

Dee Drupal.org's documentation for including libraries, it's pretty good.

- https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module

Comment: I've edited my question since I had a typo. It is using the right module name, but instead it is trying to get Theme JS rather than Module JS.